# Hide this element error data filed for kendo picker?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Hello i got some problem i have manage to use kendo picker to make my date and display the date format is wrong but however i couldnt remove the error message alway when the format day is set correctly here what i mean in my picture below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ClYo.png)

When error it display this as this is not the correct format for date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEhUw.png)

However when i change my error format to the correct one is not removing the error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIjMD.png)

Here my code for the kendo picker function

```
 $(function () {
 
             var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                 selectedDate: new Date(),
 
             });
             kendo.bind($("#change-date-collection1"), viewModel);
 
             $("#change-date-collection1").kendoValidator({
                 rules: {
                     // Implement your custom date validation.
                     dateValidation: function (input, params) {
 
                         if (input.is("[name='date']") && input.val() != "") {
                             
                             input.attr("data-datevalidation-msg","Not a valid date in dd/MM/YYYY format!");
 
                             var date = kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
                             if (date) {
                                 return true;
                              
                             }
                             return false;  
                         }
                         
                         return true;
                     }
                 },
                 messages: { //custom rules messages
                     datevalidation: function (input) {
                         // Return the message text.
                         return input.attr("data-val-datevalidation");
                     }
                 }
             });
         })
```

I would like that error be hide when the format is correct and show when the format is wrong for the date

Comment: Why do you set `input.attr("data-datevalidation-msg", ...)` in the body of validation? try to return error in the `datevalidation` of `messages` config

Comment: Thanks now how can i remove the message config ? when is correct

Comment: when you return true from your validation, kendo should disappear the error message

Comment: hmm unfortunately when i try it dont remove it

Comment: it's a typo, in the rules you are using `dateValidation` bu in the messages config you are using `datevalidation`

Comment: I've implemented an example here: https://dojo.telerik.com/@saeedShamloo/EmajoHaN/3

Comment: oh i have change that but i still got the message on it

Comment: did you check my implementation?

Comment: yes it work but can i don't use it in my form or kendopicker to select my form as i dont wan to use this validator for other input ? OH NVM did it i let it read my same input but on that class to validate working now

Comment: you can wrap your field with any html element, for example `<div id="myId"><input id="datepicker" name="date"/></div>` and try to apply validation `$("#myId").kendoValidator({...})`